# Unity 2018.2.7 100+ Errors on Project Creation

Tags: unity-game-engine

When a new project is created in Unity, there are immediately 100+ warnings and about 20 errors. The warnings are all in regards to missing meta files, and the errors are in regard to pacakages not being imported.

I have freshly installed Unity as well as VS2017 Community and that did not solve the problem.  No questions have been asked that I can find regarding this issue on either StackOverflow or the Unity Answers Forum

The errors follow this format with different file names:
`Read only asset Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro/Plugins has no meta file.`

The warnings follow this format with different file names:
`Ignoring asset refresh of Packages/com.unity.package-manager-ui/Editor/Resources/Images/Light because the folder it is in has not been imported yet!`

Comment: You need to provide at least some of the errors and warnings.

Comment: @bolov thank you for the feedback, examples have been added.

Comment: It's a bug. Go to Assets ---> Reimport All.

Comment: @Programmer, same result when the project reopened, 128 warnings and 10 errors

Comment: There is no Unity 2018.7. There is Unity 2018.2.7. If that's the version you're using then file for a bug report and roll back to  2018.2.6 until the issue is fixed

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be caused by cache files.

You can try to delete the cache files in `AppData\Local\Unity`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution, I did go to console, right click on the package.

Then select open in explorer.

I found that this package was not in the expected Users[username]\Documents file structure. Also the dates were old so it seems my reimports had had no effects. So in windows explorer I deleted the complete package.

Then I reopened the project in Unity, and at package, reimport all.

This fixed it.